# Python's cv2 gives the message "returned NULL without setting an error"

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, opencv

- I am trying to write a program that counts the number of blobs in an image.
- I have read the image from the file and converted it to grayscale using `PIL`.
- I then turn it into a `numpy` array, and pass that array through a for-loop that converts all pixels above a certain light intensity to white and all others to black.
- I have then created a new image from that array using `PIL`, and everything seems to have worked fine:

[image: Black and white image]

- I then applied the `SimpleBlobDetector` included in cv2, but it gives me this very unspecific error message:

> *<method 'detect' of 'cv2.Feature2D' objects> returned NULL without setting an error*

Does anyone know what this means, or what I can do about it? I will include my code so far, if that makes things clearer.

```py
    #Reading image from file and converting to grayscale
    filename = 'C:/Users/Windows/Desktop/Jobb/Np concentration/Microscopy images/EJ01057wellA10x.tif'
    myimg = Image.open(filename).convert('L')
    
    
    #Turning the pixels of the image into an array, and making that array editable
    imgdata = asarray(myimg)
    #print(imgdata)
    imgdata = imgdata.astype(np.float64)
    
    
    #Changing all pixels below the light intensity of 200 to black pixels, and all 
    #above to white
    for x in imgdata:
        x[x < 200] = 0 
        x[x >= 200] = 255
    
    
    #print(imgdata.shape)
    #Creating a new image from the edited array, and displaying it
    newImg = Image.fromarray(imgdata)
    newImg.show()
    
    
    #TODO: Count white blobs in newImg using a simple blob detector
    detector = cv.SimpleBlobDetector()
    keypoints = detector.detect(newImg)
    print(keypoints)
```

Comment: That's a cv2 bug. Check their bug tracker for existing reports, and if there isn't one, report it. (Make sure to include enough detail to reproduce the bug.)

Comment: (Your code might also be wrong - I haven't checked in detail - but the error message you got is from a cv2 bug.)

Comment: @EmmaJo instead of `for-loop` it's better to use **vectorization**: `imgdata[imgdata< 200] = 0, imgdata[imgdata>200]=255`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing a PIL Image object to an OpenCV function. that is incorrect usage, *not* a bug in OpenCV. OpenCV (in python) expects images to be numpy arrays. *edit:* OpenCV handles the situation badly and should raise a proper python exception (TypeError). That is a bug and you should open an issue on OpenCV's github about this.

secondly, an instance SimpleBlobDetector is created using [the `SimpleBlobDetector_create` method](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html#a1d7a06c8b8749207a978e42cd8d0cdf6). it will fail the way you did it.

you should also create params like so:

```
params = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByArea = ... # True/False, if you need it
params.maxArea = ...
# and other attributes. see docs.
detector = cv.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
```

you should not be needing PIL at all. stick to OpenCV functions for reading and writing image files (imread/imwrite) as well as grayscale conversion (cvtColor).

Comment: It might be a bad argument, but OpenCV is still mishandling it - it should produce a TypeError or something, not break the Python function call mechanism.

Comment: granted, OpenCV's python bindings have lousy error messages sometimes. feel free to submit that (minimal reproducing example) as an issue on OpenCV's github.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your answer! From what I can read, it seems that the SimpleBlobDetector outlines the blobs that are found in the image, but it doesn't actually count them. Do you know if there is a way to count them, as to actually get a number? Sorry if this is unrelated, I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: your code already contains `keypoints = detector.detect(newImg)` and `print(keypoints)`. that is the list of blobs. each "keypoint" describes a blob.